# Emulate Windows Explorer "List" view on web page?

Tags: html, windows, listview, windows-explorer

There is web page that displayed file structure - folders and files.
How to emulate Windows Explorer **"List" view** on this web page?
The order of items should be following: from top to bottom and from left to right.

I can arrange items from left to right only, by it doesn't confirm to Windows "List" view:

**Item_1    Item_2 

Item_3      Item_4 

Item_5    ...**

The next items arrangement is needed:

**Item_1     Item_4

Item_2      Item_5 

Item_3    ...**

And i stucked to do it.

Thank you for assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use **columns**.

CSS3 has them as a native function.

Until then, there are various Javascript-based solutions to achieve this, for example [this JQuery project](http://welcome.totheinter.net/2008/07/22/multi-column-layout-with-css-and-jquery/).